# How to send a JS object with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following Jquery code that sends a ajax request to add-to-cart.php.

```
        var productData = {
    "product_id": s_product_id,
    "product_opties": s_product_opties,
    "product_aantal": s_product_aantal
}

productData = JSON.stringify(productData); 

   $.ajax({
     url: 'inc/add-to-cart.php',
     dataType: "json",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: productData,
     type: 'POST',
     success: function(response) {
         alert(response.d);
     },
     error: function(e){
        console.log(e);
     }
  });
```

Add-to-cart.php:

```
  <?php
   print $_POST['product_id'];
  ?>
```

I am having two problems, the first one is that the $_POST['product_id'] does not exists when i ask for it and secondly when the ajax response returns it goes directly to the error: function and not succes function

The console log says:

```
  [object Object]{readyState: 4, responseText: "<br />  <b>N...", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
```

If the status is OK why does it jump to the error: part?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receive JSON POST with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
...
var productData = {
  'product_id':     s_product_id,
  'product_opties': product_opties,
  'product_aantal': product_aantal,
}

$.ajax({
  url: 'inc/add-to-cart.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: productData,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response.d);
  },
  error: function(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
});
...
```

Omitting the AJAX `contentType` parameter and the part where you stringify your JSON, that's already ready to be sent to your `url`, so, isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line

```
productData = JSON.stringify(productData);
```

Then do not return HTML `<br> ...` from `add_to_cart.php`, you need to return a JSON string created by the PHP function `json_encode` and NOTHING ELSE.

Like in:

```
<?php echo json_encode(array('d' => 'value of d'));
```

Answer (score 0):

First: status Code from the Webserver is 200 cause he deliverd an existing site.
Second: You dont need to stringify the json object by urself